# Drop Down menu wont stay open on hover over content below

Tags: html, css

I've tried searching the form & found similar topics but none in specific that were helpful. I'm trying to figure out why my the drop-down navigation I've made wont work when I place it in my html file.

The drop-down hover doesn't work and I noticed it seems to be effected by content under it. https://beach-riot-2017.myshopify.com/ pw: beach-riot-2017

Here's the html:
     
     
       Home

```
   <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
     <ul>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Swimwear</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrivals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Best Sellers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bikinis</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One Piece</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dresses & Rompers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tops</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bottoms</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Shop By Collection</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Spring 2017 - All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resort 2016</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jasmine Collection</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seaside Flora Collection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bridal Collection</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a>
<ul>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Beach Riot</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Press</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Stockists</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Return Policy</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
   <li><a href="#">Look Books</a>
<ul>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spring 2017</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Resort 2016s</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">BR X LUV AJ</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Summer 2016</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">SCF X Beach Riot 2016</a>
  </li>
  </ul>

 </ul>
 </nav>
```

And the CSS

```
  #primary2_nav_wrap
  {
margin-top:15px
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul
  {
list-style:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul a
  {
display:block;
color:#333;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:700;
font-size:12px;
line-height:32px;
padding:0 15px;
font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li
  {
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
  {
background:#ddd
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li:hover
  {
background:#f6f6f6
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul
  {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
background:#fff;
padding:0
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul li
  {
float:none;
width:200px
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul a
  {
line-height:120%;
padding:10px 15px
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul ul
  {
top:0;
left:100%
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
  {
display:block
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
 #primary2_nav_wrap
  {
margin-top:15px
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul
  {
list-style:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul a
  {
display:block;
color:#333;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:700;
font-size:12px;
line-height:32px;
padding:0 15px;
font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li
  {
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
  {
background:#ddd
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li:hover
  {
background:#f6f6f6
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul
  {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
background:#fff;
padding:0
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul li
  {
float:none;
width:200px
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul a
  {
line-height:120%;
padding:10px 15px
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul ul
  {
top:0;
left:100%
  }

  #primary2_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
  {
display:block
  }
```

```html
<nav id="primary2_nav_wrap">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Shop</a>
     <ul>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Swimwear</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrivals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Best Sellers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bikinis</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One Piece</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dresses & Rompers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tops</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bottoms</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dir"><a href="#">Shop By Collection</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Spring 2017 - All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resort 2016</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jasmine Collection</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seaside Flora Collection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bridal Collection</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a>
<ul>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Beach Riot</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Press</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Stockists</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Return Policy</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
   <li><a href="#">Look Books</a>
<ul>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Spring 2017</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Resort 2016s</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">BR X LUV AJ</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">Summer 2016</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dir"><a href="#">SCF X Beach Riot 2016</a>
  </li>
  </ul>

 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @Prasanga, Unfortunately that didn't do it, the drop-down will disappear whenever I however it.

Comment: The issue is still happening. Whenever I hover the drop-down the menu disappears. https://beach-riot-2017.myshopify.com/ password: beach-riot-2017

Comment: @ZackDowdy, Use this way ,  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

Comment: Thanks for your help, that still didn't work. Same problem. I tried re-doing the css completely & everything looks fine when I build it, but then when I add the code to the homepage the issue of the drop-down disappearing happens.

Comment: @ZackDowdy, Here is code that you can apply this,                                      #primary2_nav_wrap ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}